# Jersey client request to web-service

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, jersey-client

I`m trying to request to web-service by jersey client:

```
WebResource service = client.resource(UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost:8080/jersey-example-new/").build());
System.out.println(service.path("rs/").path("account/details/1").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class));
```

but I get:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/jersey-example-new/rs/account/details/1 returned a response status of 406 Not Acceptable
```

Please, note that url path `http://localhost:8080/jersey-example-new/rs/account/details/1` works in browser. What is wrong with java client request?

the endpoint code:

```
@Path("account")
public class AccountDetailsService {

    @GET
    @Path("/details/{param}")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response getAccountDetails(@PathParam("param") String accountName) {
        String output = "Account Name : " + accountName;
        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's saying, data you're returning in response is not in `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON`. Check your method for the generated output.

Comment: Show the code of your endpoint method.

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin see the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change

`System.out.println(service.path("rs/").path("account/details/1").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class));`

to 
`System.out.println(service.path("rs/").path("account/details/1").accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).get(String.class));`

You are only producing TEXT_PLAIN, but you request the media-type APPLICATION_JSON (via accept header), this is why you get the response, that the request is not acceptable.